# Android Wear not able to install the app directly from Android Studio

Tags: android, wear-os

Is the first time I try to install an Android Wear app from Android Studio. 
When I try to install the app I get the dialogbox for re-install the app. Then If I press "Yes" I get the following error:

```
$ adb shell pm uninstall com.test.wear
DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR
Error while Installing APK
```

Also, I am not able to debug.
Also I am not able to uninstall the wear app using adb.

Please give me a better solution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced the same issue and it turned out that Wear Emulator need to get Play Store Services for Wear updated after being created. See "Pair a phone with the watch AVD" section [here](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/creating.html).

Once you pair your Wear Emulator, open Android Wear app > click on gear (settings) > select Wear Emulator > Select ReSync Apps

Once done, try re-running wear app from Android Studio.

Comment: I want to debug in real device

Comment: 1. Make sure the device has debugging enabled (follow the same link and see "Setting Up a Watch"), 2. Make sure to 'Resync App' using Android Wear App to make sure Play services are updated